# Is axis of symmetry considered a true symmetry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

In most of the books when i read about optical activity of a compound this is what they say:

**A compound that does not posses any kind of symmetry is optically active. In other words chiral compounds without having any kind of of symmetry are optically active.**

However, this holds true when we refer to **plane of symmetry** or **centre of symmetry**, because molecules having **axis of symmetry** or **alternate axis of symmetry** are still optically active.

For example this compound possesses axis of symmetry but is still optically active:[image]

And therefore i am totally confused about relation of optical activity with symmetry.

Thanks for answering the question

Comment: It has to be non trivial. A rotation of $0$ or $2\pi$ about an axis being trivial.

Comment: No, this is not what they say. If you skip a few words from a meaningful sentence, it is quite easy to arrive at nonsense. It is not just _"any kind of symmetry"_; it is _"any kind of **inversion** symmetry"_, or _"any kind of symmetry **with determinant -1**"_. Rotational symmetry does not apply, though it is surely true and real (and non-trivial, for that matter).

Answer (score 3):

A molecule is chiral ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_%28chemistry%29#Definition), [2](http://goldbook.iupac.org/C01058.html)) if it does not have an improper axis of rotation. Since your drawing does not seem to show the [meso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meso_compound) form of 2,3-dichlorobutane, it is optically active.

Answer (score 2):

This is to complement the answer given already and to address @Ivan Neretin's comment under OP's question. It is an example that generally (with lots of asterisks) rotations cannot be excluded. This is a copy from J. March's  6ed (p. 158).

[image]

From the text:

> Such compounds possess ... an alternating axis of symmetry as in 1

Of course Ivan is correct that you only care for "determinant $-1$" motions or else orientation reversing and in this case we use a rotation by $\pi$ which has determinant 1 (or else belongs to $SO_3$). My group theory is not as good since I am an organic chemist but I think the actual symmetry element is something like $\rho_{\pi/2} \circ r = 1$ whereas the rotation element above is $\rho_\pi=(\rho_{\pi/2} \circ r)\circ (\rho'_{\pi/2} \circ r')=1 \circ 1=1$ and it does have determinant 1 but is not one of the symmetry group elements (in the sense that $x^{34}$ is in $C_4=\{1,x,x^2,x^3 \}$ but only as $x^{34}=x^2$ ).

To make things more complicated March is defining an "alternating axis of symmetry" as:

> An alternating axis of symmetry 17 of order n is an axis such that
>   when an object containing such an axis is rotated by 360/n about the
>   axis and then reflection is effected across a plane at right angles to
>   the axis, a new object is obtained that is indistinguishable from the
>   original one

So it appears that in the example of (1) we talk of $Z_4$ symmetry (if we call $Z$ the alternating axis subgroup) and  $Z_4 \sim C_2$

Finally, I think that **(1)** is an extreme example and almost always for organic compounds chirality (or not) is determined by the lack (or not) of a plane of symmetry

Comment: isn't symmetry of axis a disqualifying property for a molecule being an isomer?