# Conditions for molecular dissymmetry

Tags: symmetry, optical-properties

In my textbook, under the topic "Asymmetric and Dissymmetric Compounds", the following statement is given:

> A molecule which does not possess plane of symmetry, centre of symmetry, and alternating axis of symmetry is called dissymmetric.

Why the definition didn't include the "axis of symmetry" as a condition for molecular dissymmetry?

Comment: Because axes of symmetry are irrelevant for the question at hand.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/104409/use-of-axis-of-symmetry/104411#104411

Comment: For the record, over a 10-year career in chemistry, I have never heard anyone use the word "dissymmetric." The proper word is "chiral."

Comment: @Zhe, Thank you for your reply. Actually, it is given in my textbook like that. I am also used to the term chiral, but not dissymmetric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(chemistry)):

> A chiral compound can contain no improper axis of rotation ($S_{n}$), which includes planes of symmetry and inversion center. Chiral molecules are always dissymmetric (lacking $S_{n}$) but not always asymmetric (lacking all symmetry elements except the trivial identity). Asymmetric molecules are always chiral.

That means that a dyssymetric molecule lacks of $S_{n}$ axis(planes of symmetry and inversion centers) but can have $C_{n}$ axis of rotation. For example the following molecule is dissymetric: it does not have any plane of symmetry or inversion center but it has a $C_{2}$ axis of rotation(the "axis of rotation" is a synonyms of the "axis of symmetry" you mentioned in your question).

[image]